# PHP soapclient call error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have the asmx webservice url : http://newxilnexbackend.cloudapp.net/XilnexNewReg.asmx and i am trying to call this web service using php soapclient but i am stuck at this error (Fatal error: SOAP Fault: (faultcode: soap:Server, faultstring: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwroot\captcha.php on line 27). i have tried everything to fix this but no solution. can anyone help me to find out that which part i am doing it wrongly.

this is my php code :

```
enter code here$tes = 'hi';
try{
$client = new SoapClient("http://newxilnexbackend.cloudapp.net/XilnexNewReg.asmx?WSDL");
$result = $client->RegistrationOfNewCompany(array(
$tes, $tes, $tes
));
header("Location: http://webapp.xilnex.com/"); 
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring:          {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}}
```

i have also tried this way but got same error:

```
$result = $client->RegistrationOfNewCompany(array(
EmailAddress=>$tes, 
CompanyName=>$tes, 
Name=>$tes
));
```